# How to iterate over a list and draw a table with the goterm package?

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I am trying to rapidly prototype something with [goterm](https://github.com/buger/goterm/blob/master/examples/table_example.go). I have a list of user objects in a struct. I want to output a header row (works) then iterate over the list (works) and add a row for each user. However, with the code below, nothing renders to the console. No blank lines. Nothing. The program just returns. I have gotten the linked example to work with just the header row and a data row. Appending to the table by iterating as I am is not working. I am certain I am missing something very basic. Help would be appreciated. I will continue hacking away.

```
func usersListOutputConsole(users *data.UserList) {
  userTable := tm.NewTable(0, 10, 5, ' ', 0)
  fmt.Fprintf(userTable, "ID\tName\tFull Name\tEmail\n") // the header row
  for _, user := range users.Data {
    fmt.Fprintf(userTable, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", user.ID,   user.Attributes["name"], user.Attributes["full_name"], user.Attributes["email"])
  }
  tm.Println(userTable)
  tm.Flush()
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information, or a reproducible example. If you can run the linked example, drop your code directly in there and see what happens. Try changin the Fprintf's to print to stdout and see what you get.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll mock one up shortly. I have used spew.Dump() within the loop to verify the data is there. It's definitely a goterm problem (my usage thereof, of course!).

Comment: @n8gard: It works for me. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure you have `func main` and all libs imported? How's your function called?

Comment: I'm creating a full, reproducible example and will have it up in a bit. But I know the libs are working because the single data-row example does work. Just not when I iterate through a list and attempt to put multiple rows in the table. A subtle thing I am missing, I'm sure. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I found that everything was, in fact, working properly. What I had failed to catch in the differences between goterm and Go's native tabwriter is that the former is more of an actual terminal program and redraws the screen. Embarrassingly, expecting scrolling output, my terminal window was too small for the 50+ rows being output. After realizing this and finding that I wanted the scrolling output of tabwriter, I switched and minutes later everything was working as expected. goterm is a fantastic package if you're looking for an interactive-like terminal program. It's not what I wanted though I had been attracted to it for its formatting capabilities. In short, RTFM.